# event loop epoll timer out of sync issue

Tags: c, events, epoll

I am writing an event loop. I want to have timers. I will implement the timers using epoll timeout. I will have a timing wheel and will mod the current time by wheel size to get the slot in the wheel. But I think there may be an issue with this. Let's say the current time is 1.99999999999, and I check the wheel and the next event is in 4 seconds. Since the next event is in 4 seconds, I sleep for 4 seconds. However since the time was just on the edge of becoming 2, when I wake from the 4 seconds, the time will be 6 seconds. Therefore I will have missed my event which was meant to trigger in 4 seconds since that should happen at time 5 seconds.

I could just scrap the timing wheel and use a binary heap. That way I could just check if the time of the event is less than or equal to the current time. But this comes at the cost of performance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? If you have an issue with existing code, show a minimal reproduction with expected and actual behavior. The timing wheel seems like premature optimization unless you're actually expecting millions of scheduled events.  Have you looked at [POSIX `timer_create`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html)?  Sounds like that would support hundreds of simultaneous timers if that's all you need.  If you end up with a list, maybe you should sort it so you can stop iterating when current work is done.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the comments earlier: not really enough detail. I would second the comment from @erik258 about timer_create() and I would further add that for *Linux-specific* integration of epoll and timers, take a look at the man pages for `timerfd_create()` as well.